# Calculating homology groups of $(S^n, \{x_1,x_2,...,x_k\})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

I tried to the find the homology groups the following way. I'm not sure if it is correct.

By excision, $H_m(S^n, \{x_1,x_2,...,x_k\})\cong \widetilde H_m (S^n/F),$ where $F=\{x_1,...,x_k\}$.

$\color{red}{S^n/F\simeq S^n\vee \overbrace{(S^1\vee S^1\vee...\vee S^1)}^{k-1 \text{ copies}}}$. .This is because of the following image:
[image]

So we have $\widetilde H_m(S^n/F)=\widetilde H_m(S^n)\oplus \widetilde H_m(S^1)^{k-1}$

It follows that $\widetilde H_0(S^n/F)=0\implies \widetilde H_0(S^n/F)=Z, H_1(S^n/F)=Z^{k-1}, H_n(S^n/F)=Z$

$ H_m(S^n/F)=0, m\ne 0,1,n$.

Is this correct, in particular the red colored part? Thanks

Comment: Instead of $\cong$ (homeomorphism), I meant $\simeq$ (homotopy equivalence).

Comment: I didn't read the rest of the parts but the red part is correct.